# append rows from dataframe to google sheets

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab and I have a dataframe that I would like to append into a google spreadsheets. At the end of my code, I am using this:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()
```

```
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

wb = gc.open_by_key('1OpK7nHZXJTlFKRR24iPjLRXN-z-Sf4eNI8rVE6fucf8')

ws = wb.worksheet('example')

ws.append_rows([df.columns.to_list()] + df.to_numpy().tolist())
```

I would like to append the dataframe in the the last row without dataframe headers. How can I get this?

example:

current_dataframe in google sheets:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 24 |
| Victor | 3 |

After I run my code, I'd like to see the same dataframe with the new info, like this:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 24 |
| Victor | 3 |
| Juan | 7 |

and not like this:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 24 |
| Victor | 3 |
| name | age |
| Juan | 7 |

Comment: Have a look: https://medium.com/@jb.ranchana/write-and-append-dataframes-to-google-sheets-in-python-f62479460cf0

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns.values.to_list()
```

Probably it will work.